# Call a function after another function has completed

Tags: php, function

Why would it not work to call the get_accounts() function at the end of the delete_account() function?

```
function get_accounts() {
    require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
    try {
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM account");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo ("ERROR: Data could not be retrieved from the database." . $e);
        exit;
    }
    $accounts = $results->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $accounts;
}



if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'delete_account')) {


            require("config.php");
            require("database.php");

            $deleteAccount = $_POST['account'];


            try {
                $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM account WHERE account_id_PK = ?");
                $results->bindValue(1, $deleteAccount);
                $results->execute();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "ERROR: Data could not be removed from the database. " . $e;
                exit;
            }
            echo($deleteAccount);
get_accounts();
};
```

Basically, I want to run the delete_accounts() function and at the end I would like to run the get_accounts() function, which will refresh the list of accounts on the page after the selected account has been deleted.  I can't seem to call a function from within another function, no matter what I try.

Comment: Where is the `delete_account()` function?

Comment: I'd rather do a redirect after the delete_account request to call up get_accounts. That's less side-effectsy. Also, since delete_account is changing the application state it should not be possible through a GET request since GET requests are reserved for idempotent and safe operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the finally part of the try catch & remove the '`exit();`'

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == 'delete_account')) {

            require("config.php");
            require("database.php");

            $deleteAccount = $_POST['account'];

            try {
                $results = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM account WHERE account_id_PK = ?");
                $results->bindValue(1, $deleteAccount);
                $results->execute();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "ERROR: Data could not be removed from the database. " . $e;
            }finally{ 
               get_accounts();
            }
            echo($deleteAccount);
}
```

Comment: OK! after updating to PHP 5.5, this worked.  Thanks!

Comment: actually, I spoke too soon.  this didn't work aferall.  The function in the finally block is not in bold font like they normally are when they're recognized in Sublime Text.

Comment: get_accounts() returns has a return variable that in this context you are not using, maybe you need to change your code so that it does? The finally block will execute after the code in the try and IF an exception occurs after that. It will always fire, just depends upon your implementation as to what happens next...